# Timescale for bar charts in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I created a line chart the image below using this code:

```
p=figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(df.index,df.counter, line_width=2)
show(p)
```

[image]

However, if I try to do the same using a bar chart with this code:

```
data = {"x":df.counter}
b = Bar(data, xscale='datetime')
show(b)
```

the scale is not correct:

[image]

Any possible reason to this, and could it be fixed?